# How to get a specific value from a result field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql query which returns list of details for a specific id. The result contains many fields like id, name, location, date, profile and extra_info fields. The extra_info fields contain different kind of information added by the client like what kind of payment, shipping details ,url of pictures for reference etc.

```
 <?php
 $result = mysql_query("MYSQL query" );
 if (!$result) {
 echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
$rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // id
echo $row[20]; // the extra_info field
?>
```

**Current output:
      //extra_info field

http://example.com/ext/lib/exe/process.php?t=87458+52&w=466&h=471&:forum_pic:queue_hasb_bunny_khd_tyun_02300.jpg, Imm processing,http://example.com/storage/high resolution/i-white bunny-tyun.jpg,only cash payment,process after christmas, handle with care notification, date: 2-5-2015**

What is needed is to display only the image urls from extra_info field. I am only able to echo the complete extra_info field. How to get display the image urls from extra_info field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image url is at the first position for sure you can do an explode

```
$extraFieldData = explode(',', $row[20]);
echo $extraFieldData[0];
```

Comment: But not always the url of the image is placed as row[20], is there a generic way to see if the extra_field contains a url and if it has the url, then to count for its position and then display it?